# how to get class details recursively in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have got a python script based on selenium to do some automation and getting stock market data.

[image]

I can individually access elements, but I want to this recursively for dates present.

Can anybody show me in selenium using python how to do it..

My code to get the numbers:

```
all_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="number"]')
for element in all_elements:
    print("{}".format(element.text))
```

Any better way, it will be great

Comment: can i know what your expected output will be? maybe i can help

Comment: This is not really clear, what output do you expect from the recursion?

Comment: I wanna get date and the corresponding numbers, any way to get that

Comment: something like, after I get the date, then the following class of number will belong to that date, next 6 number for next date, likewise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can locate the dates and use them to locate the corresponding numbers

```
all_dates = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="date"]')
for date in all_dates:
    numbers = date.find_elements_by_xpath('.//following-sibling::td[@class="number"]')
    print(date.text)
    for number in numbers:
        print(number.text)
```